# Overhead of a .NET array?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, overhead

I was trying to determine the overhead of the header on a .NET array (in a 32-bit process) using this code:

```
long bytes1 = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
object[] array = new object[10000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        array[i] = new int[1];
long bytes2 = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
array[0] = null; // ensure no garbage collection before this point

Console.WriteLine(bytes2 - bytes1);
// Calculate array overhead in bytes by subtracting the size of 
// the array elements (40000 for object[10000] and 4 for each 
// array), and dividing by the number of arrays (10001)
Console.WriteLine("Array overhead: {0:0.000}", 
                  ((double)(bytes2 - bytes1) - 40000) / 10001 - 4);
Console.Write("Press any key to continue...");
Console.ReadKey();
```

The result was

```
    204800
    Array overhead: 12.478
```

In a 32-bit process, object[1] should be the same size as int[1], but in fact the overhead jumps by 3.28 bytes to

```
    237568
    Array overhead: 15.755
```

Anyone know why?

(By the way, if anyone's curious, the overhead for non-array objects, e.g. (object)i in the loop above, is about 8 bytes (8.384). I heard it's 16 bytes in 64-bit processes.)

Comment: Is that in a Debug or a Release build?

Comment: Hmm, I actually don't know, I was using SnippetCompiler. When I switched to Visual Studio, the results changed slightly: 11.92 for int[1] and 15.94 for object[1], regardless of whether it was a Debug or Release build.

Comment: Oh, I also changed to 100000 to reduce the affect of allocation granularity in the memory manager.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Here's a slightly neater (IMO) short but complete program to demonstrate the same thing:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    const int Size = 100000;

    static void Main()
    {
        object[] array = new object[Size];
        long initialMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
        for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
        {
            array[i] = new string[0];
        }
        long finalMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
        GC.KeepAlive(array);

        long total = finalMemory - initialMemory;

        Console.WriteLine("Size of each element: {0:0.000} bytes",
                          ((double)total) / Size);
    }
}
```

But I get the same results - the overhead for any reference type array is 16 bytes, whereas the overhead for any value type array is 12 bytes. I'm still trying to work out why that is, with the help of the CLI spec. Don't forget that reference type arrays are covariant, which may be relevant...

EDIT: With the help of cordbg, I can confirm Brian's answer - the type pointer of a reference-type array is the same regardless of the actual element type. Presumably there's some funkiness in `object.GetType()` (which is non-virtual, remember) to account for this.

So, with code of:

```
object[] x = new object[1];
string[] y = new string[1];
int[] z = new int[1];
z[0] = 0x12345678;
lock(z) {}
```

We end up with something like the following:

```
Variables:
x=(0x1f228c8) <System.Object[]>
y=(0x1f228dc) <System.String[]>
z=(0x1f228f0) <System.Int32[]>

Memory:
0x1f228c4: 00000000 003284dc 00000001 00326d54 00000000 // Data for x
0x1f228d8: 00000000 003284dc 00000001 00329134 00000000 // Data for y
0x1f228ec: 00000000 00d443fc 00000001 12345678 // Data for z
```

Note that I've dumped the memory 1 word *before* the value of the variable itself.

For `x` and `y`, the values are:

- The sync block, used for locking the hash code (or a *thin lock* - see Brian's comment)
- Type pointer
- Size of array
- Element type pointer
- Null reference (first element)

For `z`, the values are:

- Sync block
- Type pointer
- Size of array
- 0x12345678 (first element)

Different value type arrays (byte[], int[] etc) end up with different type pointers, whereas all reference type arrays use the same type pointer, but have a different element type pointer. The element type pointer is the same value as you'd find as the type pointer for an object of that type. So if we looked at a string object's memory in the above run, it would have a type pointer of 0x00329134.

The word before the type pointer certainly has *something* to do with either the monitor or the hash code: calling `GetHashCode()` populates that bit of memory, and I believe the default `object.GetHashCode()` obtains a sync block to ensure hash code uniqueness for the lifetime of the object. However, just doing `lock(x){}` didn't do anything, which surprised me...

All of this is only valid for "vector" types, by the way - in the CLR, a "vector" type is a single-dimensional array with a lower-bound of 0. Other arrays will have a different layout - for one thing, they'd need the lower bound stored...

So far this has been experimentation, but here's the guesswork - the reason for the system being implemented the way it has. From here on, I really am just guessing.

- All `object[]` arrays can share the same JIT code. They're going to behave the same way in terms of memory allocation, array access, `Length` property and (importantly) the layout of references for the GC. Compare that with value type arrays, where different value types may have different GC "footprints" (e.g. one might have a byte and then a reference, others will have no references at all, etc).
- Every time you assign a value within an `object[]` the runtime needs to check that it's valid. It needs to check that the type of the object whose reference you're using for the new element value is compatible with the element type of the array. For instance:

  ```
  object[] x = new object[1];
  object[] y = new string[1];
  x[0] = new object(); // Valid
  y[0] = new object(); // Invalid - will throw an exception
  ```

This is the covariance I mentioned earlier. Now given that this is going to happen for *every single assignment*, it makes sense to reduce the number of indirections. In particular, I suspect you don't really want to blow the cache by having to go to the type object for each assigment to get the element type. I *suspect* (and my x86 assembly isn't good enough to verify this) that the test is something like:

- Is the value to be copied a null reference? If so, that's fine. (Done.)
- Fetch the type pointer of the object the reference points at.
- Is that type pointer the same as the element type pointer (simple binary equality check)? If so, that's fine. (Done.)
- Is that type pointer assignment-compatible with the element type pointer? (Much more complicated check, with inheritance and interfaces involved.) If so, that's fine - otherwise, throw an exception.

If we can terminate the search in the first three steps, there's not a lot of indirection - which is good for something that's going to happen as often as array assignments. None of this needs to happen for value type assignments, because that's statically verifiable.

So, that's why I believe reference type arrays are slightly bigger than value type arrays.

Great question - really interesting to delve into it :)

Comment: Philip's first link (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/arrays.aspx) has an answer: "Reference types also have an element type field that precedes the data; it does seem redundant since the array's method table could instead extract the necessary type information. The presence of the element type as a field does allow the elements type information to be extracted quickly without an virtual call indirection and function call, which is important for features like array covariance."

Comment: Jon, I believe I found the missing four bytes. Please see my answer. If you want I can add the necessary dumps from WinDbg to illustrate.

Comment: And btw +1 for highlighting this fact.

Comment: The bytes you see in front of the instance is the SyncBlock entry. However, it is a bit more complicated than that, as this field is used for both locking and hash code as you mention. CLR 2.0 introduced an optimization called thin locks. As I understand it the thin lock can be stored directly in the SyncBlock field provided that it isn't used for the hash code and that the lock is not contented. If either of these occur, the lock is "promoted" to a real SyncBlock lock. The upcoming Advanced .NET debugging book (http://my.safaribooksonline.com/0321589637) has additional details.

Comment: Ah... and the thin lock is wiped out after the lock is exited. That makes sense - and I've now verified that indeed, if you dump the memory while *in* a lock statement, that word gets a value.

Comment: With .NET 5 when I run the `GetTotalMemory` test with `int`, `byte`, `string` and `double` empty arrays are 12 bytes, including `string`, for all types in 32-bit. But 4-byte aligned, eg. `new byte[1]` is 16 bytes not 13. Also, empty arrays are 24 bytes for all types in 64-bit and 8-byte aligned, eg. `new int[1]` is 32 bytes not 28. Tested on Windows 10 with runtime version 5.0.203.

Answer (score 23):

Array is a reference type. All reference types carry two additional word fields. The type reference and a SyncBlock index field, which among other things is used to implement locks in the CLR. So the type overhead on reference types is 8 bytes on 32 bit. On top of that the array itself also stores the length which is another 4 bytes. This brings the total overhead to 12 bytes.

And I just learned from Jon Skeet's answer, arrays of reference types has an additional 4 bytes overhead. This can be confirmed using WinDbg. It turns out that the additional word is another type reference for the type stored in the array. All arrays of reference types are stored internally as `object[]`, with the additional reference to the type object of the actual type. So a `string[]` is really just an `object[]` with an additional type reference to the type `string`. For details please see below.

Values stored in arrays: Arrays of reference types hold references to objects, so each entry in the array is the size of a reference (i.e. 4 bytes on 32 bit). Arrays of value types store the values inline and thus each element will take up the size of the type in question.

This question may also be of interest: [C# List<double> size vs double[] size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508215/c-listdouble-size-vs-double-size/1508232#1508232)

**Gory Details**

Consider the following code

```
var strings = new string[1];
var ints = new int[1];

strings[0] = "hello world";
ints[0] = 42;
```

Attaching WinDbg shows the following:

First let's take a look at the value type array.

```
0:000> !dumparray -details 017e2acc 
Name: System.Int32[]
MethodTable: 63b9aa40
EEClass: 6395b4d4
Size: 16(0x10) bytes
Array: Rank 1, Number of elements 1, Type Int32
Element Methodtable: 63b9aaf0
[0] 017e2ad4
    Name: System.Int32
    MethodTable 63b9aaf0
    EEClass: 6395b548
    Size: 12(0xc) bytes
     (C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll)
    Fields:
          MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
    63b9aaf0  40003f0        0         System.Int32  1 instance       42 m_value <=== Our value

0:000> !objsize 017e2acc 
sizeof(017e2acc) =           16 (        0x10) bytes (System.Int32[])

0:000> dd 017e2acc -0x4
017e2ac8  00000000 63b9aa40 00000001 0000002a <=== That's the value
```

First we dump the array and the one element with value of 42. As can be seen the size is 16 bytes. That is 4 bytes for the `int32` value itself, 8 bytes for regular reference type overhead and another 4 bytes for the length of the array.

The raw dump shows the SyncBlock, the method table for `int[]`, the length, and the value of 42 (2a in hex). Notice that the SyncBlock is located just in front of the object reference.

Next, let's look at the `string[]` to find out what the additional word is used for.

```
0:000> !dumparray -details 017e2ab8 
Name: System.String[]
MethodTable: 63b74ed0
EEClass: 6395a8a0
Size: 20(0x14) bytes
Array: Rank 1, Number of elements 1, Type CLASS
Element Methodtable: 63b988a4
[0] 017e2a90
    Name: System.String
    MethodTable: 63b988a4
    EEClass: 6395a498
    Size: 40(0x28) bytes <=== Size of the string
     (C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll)
    String:     hello world    
    Fields:
          MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
    63b9aaf0  4000096        4         System.Int32  1 instance       12 m_arrayLength
    63b9aaf0  4000097        8         System.Int32  1 instance       11 m_stringLength
    63b99584  4000098        c          System.Char  1 instance       68 m_firstChar
    63b988a4  4000099       10        System.String  0   shared   static Empty
    >> Domain:Value  00226438:017e1198 <<
    63b994d4  400009a       14        System.Char[]  0   shared   static WhitespaceChars
    >> Domain:Value  00226438:017e1760 <<

0:000> !objsize 017e2ab8 
sizeof(017e2ab8) =           60 (        0x3c) bytes (System.Object[]) <=== Notice the underlying type of the string[]

0:000> dd 017e2ab8 -0x4
017e2ab4  00000000 63b74ed0 00000001 63b988a4 <=== Method table for string
017e2ac4  017e2a90 <=== Address of the string in memory

0:000> !dumpmt 63b988a4
EEClass: 6395a498
Module: 63931000
Name: System.String
mdToken: 02000024  (C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll)
BaseSize: 0x10
ComponentSize: 0x2
Number of IFaces in IFaceMap: 7
Slots in VTable: 196
```

First we dump the array and the string. Next we dump the size of the `string[]`. Notice that WinDbg lists the type as `System.Object[]` here. The object size in this case includes the string itself, so the total size is the 20 from the array plus the 40 for the string.

By dumping the raw bytes of the instance we can see the following: First we have the SyncBlock, then follows the method table for `object[]`, then the length of the array. After that we find the additional 4 bytes with the reference to the method table for string. This can be verified by the dumpmt command as shown above. Finally we find the single reference to the actual string instance.

**In conclusion**

The overhead for arrays can be broken down as follows (on 32 bit that is)

- 4 bytes SyncBlock
- 4 bytes for Method table (type reference) for the array itself
- 4 bytes for Length of array
- Arrays of reference types adds another 4 bytes to hold the method table of the actual element type (reference type arrays are `object[]` under the hood)

I.e. the overhead is **12 bytes for value type arrays** and **16 bytes for reference type arrays**.

Comment: object[1] and int[1] are both reference types.

Comment: I think you mean "_two_ additional fields"

Comment: @Qwertie: Yes arrays are reference types. I was just pointing out the somewhat surprising fact that object takes up additional 4 bytes. I have removed the comment as it doesn't have anything to do with arrays.

Comment: I read at http://codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/arrays.aspx that the additional 4 bytes are for an "element type field". I assume it is used to save a single indirection, since the CLR designers could have included that field within the virtual function table of each array type instead. In other words, I think they could have stored the field once per reference array type, but instead they chose to store a copy of the field in every array.

Comment: @Qwertie: That is already accounted for (the "type reference" in my answer). All reference types has this field.

Comment: @Brian: Looks like we were both expanding our answers at the same time. Could you check that mine looks correct to you? I've also given some guesswork as to why this is the case :)

Comment: @Jon, I included a comment about the SyncBlock field on your answer. As far as I can tell our stories are pretty much in sync.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are making some faulty assumptions while measuring, as the memory allocation (via GetTotalMemory) during your loop may be different than the actual required memory for just the arrays - the memory may be allocated in larger blocks, there may be other objects in memory that are reclaimed during the loop, etc.

Here's some info for you on array overhead:

- [Arrays Undocumented](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/arrays.aspx)
- [Article by Jeffrey Richter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301755.aspx)
- [.Net Type Internals](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/net_type_internals.aspx)

Comment: Faulty assumptions such as...?

Comment: Faulty assumptions such as - GetTotalMemory is only increased by the array allocations in your loop, and only by exacly the amount required.

Comment: I didn't assume that. I did assume that as Size approaches infinity, GetTotalMemory would converge with the memory consumption of the arrays, but I realize I didn't go close enough to infinity at first.

Answer (score 1):

Because heap management (since you deal with GetTotalMemory)  can only allocate rather large blocks, which latter are allocated by smaller chunks for programmer purposes by CLR.

Comment: Isn't memory allocated in 4 KB or 8 KB pages? In that case the maximum error is 2-4% in this example. I tried increasing the test size to 100,000 arrays, but this made little difference: int[1] overhead changed to 11.924 and object[1] overhead was 15.938: still a 3 byte difference.

Comment: @Qwertie: Actually the CLR allocates in rather big chunks from the OS. On 32 bit segments are typically around 16 MB. These segments are then used as storage for the managed heap.

Comment: It seems to me GetTotalMemory works on a granularity of about 8 KB.