# .NET Memory profiler wanted

Tags: .net

I need a good memory profiler for .net, it would be ideal if it shown types of objects currently loaded in memory. Usually I use DotTrace but it does not seem to show object types.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463711

Comment: Another related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678588

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you looked at the [ANTS Memory profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_memory_profiler/index.htm) from RedGate?

Answer (score 1):

We've had success with [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/dotnet/download/index.jsp).