# Which size does an array have in memory?

Tags: c#, arrays

I wonder which size an array has. I thought of `size * sizeof(item) + sizeof(pointer)` but how many bytes are allocated for being able to reference the array?

Comment: use Garbage Collection class System.GC , and test it for anything you want

Comment: Note that sadly the other question I have linked doesn't speak of x64 bits. Sunday I'll try to do some experiments.

Comment: Done some experiments... At 64 bits the overhead of arrays are: 24 bits for value-type arrays and 32 bits for reference-type arrays.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The overhead of arrays in bytes are:

```
Architecture | Value Type Array | Reference Type Array
    x86              12                   16
    x64              24                   32
```

You can calc these values with

```
using System;

class Test
{
    const int Size = 100000;

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Running at {0} bits", IntPtr.Size * 8);

        Tester<string>();
        Tester<double>();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void Tester<T>()
    {
        var array = new object[Size];
        long initialMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

        for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
        {
            array[i] = new T[0];
        }

        long finalMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

        GC.KeepAlive(array);

        long total = finalMemory - initialMemory;

        Console.WriteLine("Size of each {0}[]: {1:0.000} bytes", typeof(T).Name,
                          ((double)total) / Size);
    }
}
```

This code is a modified version of the one from here [Overhead of a .NET array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589669/overhead-of-a-net-array)

Clearly you have to execute it at 32 and at 64 bits.

To this overhead you have to add: the elements of the array (so `size * sizeof(element)`) plus at least a reference to the array that you'll need to have (so `IntPtr.Size`).

Note that there are some inconsistencies I've noticed. If I create `double[1]`, so arrays of a single double, each one of them is perfectly aligned on the 8 byte boundary, but the space used seems to be only 20 bytes/array (at 32 bits, so 12 + sizeof(double)). This is clearly impossible, because 20 isn't divisible by 8. I think the `GC.GetTotalMemory` is "ignoring" the hole between objects. This could be an additional overhead of some bytes/array (depending on the type of elements of the array). For `byte[1]` the medium size is 16 bytes/array (at 32 bits, so 12 + sizeof(byte) + 3). This seems to be more correct.