# Real size in memory of an array

Tags: c#

If I have:

```
int[] d = {1,2,3};
```

which is the exact allocated space in memory of the array object referenced by `d`?

Is it only `3 * 4 = 12` byte or there are other bytes like in Java (i.e. object header, padding, and so on)?

P.S.
I noticed that I can't use `sizeof` operator...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Memory measurement in managed languages is more complex like unmanaged ones like c#, so `sizeof` is not as straight-forward an operation.

Comment: Have a look here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589669/overhead-of-a-net-array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589669/overhead-of-a-net-array) It shows hat the overhead for a reference type array is 16 bytes wheras the overhead for a value type array is 12 bytes.

Comment: Yes, there are more bytes also allocated. Where did you get the idea of `sizeof`? This is not C++. This is completely different language. Actually, you can do something like sizeof with [Marshal.SizeOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/5s4920fa(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Have another look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207592/getting-the-size-of-a-field-in-bytes-with-c-sharp#207605